# How the synchronization between the poller and the service activator is handled by default in Spring Integration 4.3

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-4

Is it synchronized by default ? if No then how it is done in Spring Integration 4.3

Comment: Please, give us more info about your concern. The polling channel adapter sends the data into a message channel. The service activator is subscribed to that channel to receive messages. So, probably your question is more about the nature of this or that `MessageChannnel` impl: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations ?